# Trying to fix a Swift 3 error; Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : AnyObject]]' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift3

**Hear me out before you become condescending and down vote my question to oblivion **

1. Yes, I have googled this problem and have gotten many a results pointing directly to StackOverflow
2. Yes, I have tried the many solutions that I have been pointed to but they end up having one of three results: There is a response with a high (relative) answer, that does not work because its for Swift 2 and not 3; The answer is for Swift 3 but in the comments it has something along the lines of "Don't do this! It will give you more troubles later on" or "That didn't work at all for me"; Or there is a long seemingly helpful paragraph that insults the asker and then doesn't actually answer the question
3. Yes, I understand this is considered a duplicate question but again if you look through past answer, you'll see absolutely nothing is clear. It's just users shouting they're right and the asker is wrong.

This is why I'm asking this question now. To hopefully have engagement on the topic, get it answered with clear instructions, and lay it to rest until Swift 4 comes out and breaks it.

---

I'm building a iOS app that shows a list of deals. These deals exist on a server in a JSON Block formatted [like this](https://api.myjson.com/bins/28h8j). From the examples and tutorials I have found the code I have put together looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "SOME URL")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

            do{

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]

                if let deals = json["deals"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                    for deal in deals {

                        if let title = deals["title"] as? String {

                            if let description = deals["description"] as? String {
                                print(title,description)
                                TableData.append(title)
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }

        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

The error I am getting is: Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : AnyObject]]' with an index of type 'String'. Which occurs at: `if let title = deals["title"] as? String {` and `if let description = deals["description"] as? String {`

I don't know what to do on how to fix this. An original error I had was different and to solve that I added `as! [String:AnyObject]` at line 14 as suggested by another SO post. This caused the error I'm having now. What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Typo:  `deal["title"]` and  `deal["description"]` (singular). By the way, in Swift 3 the JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]` and use native `URL` and `URLRequest`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of accessing `deals`, you should access `deal`

```
if let title = deals["title"] as? String
```

should be

```
if let title = deal["title"] as? String
```

The same for description. This is because `deals` is an array, not a dictionary. `deal` is the dictionary